# Enabling Keycloak Authentication for Activemq Jetty

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, keycloak, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am trying to enable keycloak authentication into Activemq (5.16.3 Linux RHEL7.9) using the SOPS located at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_jetty9_adapter

After extracting the Jetty 9 Adaptor into my root of Activemq (in this case /opt/activemq/current/ which is a symlink to /opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/) and creating the files /opt/activemq/current/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="securityHandler">
        <Set name="authenticator">
            <New class="org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator">
            </New>
        </Set>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

/opt/activemq/current/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm" : "<REALM>",
  "resource" : "activemq",
  "auth-server-url" : "https://<FQDN>:8443/"
  "ssl-required" : "external",
  "use-resource-role-mappings" : false,
  "enable-cors" : true,
  "cors-max-age" : 1000,
  "cors-allowed-methods" : "POST, PUT, DELETE, GET",
  "bearer-only" : false,
  "enable-basic-auth" : false,
  "expose-token" : true,
   "credentials" : {
      "secret" : "<Secret_id>"
   },

   "connection-pool-size" : 20,
   "disable-trust-manager": false,
   "allow-any-hostname" : false,
   "truststore" : "/etc/pki/keycloak/truststore.jks",
   "truststore-password" : "<password>",
   "client-keystore" : "/etc/pki/keycloak/keystore.jks",
   "client-keystore-password" : "<password>",
   "token-minimum-time-to-live" : 10,
   "min-time-between-jwks-requests" : 10,
   "public-key-cache-ttl": 86400
}
```

modifying the /opt/activemq/current/modules/keycloak.mod

```
# Keycloak Jetty Adapter
#

[depend]
server
security

[lib]
/opt/activemq/current/lib/keycloak/*.jar
```

and adding
`-D--add-to-startd=keycloak`
to the ACTIVEMQ_OPTS in /opt/activemq/current/bin/activemq.

I am getting the following error when trying to start activemq.

```
JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3//conf/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3//tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3//conf:/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/ -Dactivemq.base=/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/ -Dactivemq.conf=/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3//conf -Dactivemq.data=/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3//data
Extensions classpath:
  [/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/lib,/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/lib/camel,/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/lib/optional,/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/lib/web,/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@5bc79255: startup date [Fri Nov 12 16:47:31 AEDT 2021]; root of context hierarchy
 WARN | Config error at <Set name="authenticator">
            <New class="org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator"/>
        </Set>
 WARN | Config error at <Get name="securityHandler"><Set name="authenticator">
            <New class="org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator"/>
        </Set></Get>
 WARN | Error applying file:///opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml
 WARN | Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2e9fda69{/admin,file:///opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/webapps/admin/,UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:538)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.get(XmlConfiguration.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration.lambda$configure$0(JettyWebXmlConfiguration.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.runWithServerClassAccess(WebAppClassLoader.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration.configure(JettyWebXmlConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
 WARN | unavailable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing brokerURL (specified via org.apache.activemq.brokerURL init-Param) or embedded broker
    at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.initConnectionFactory(WebClient.java:279)
    at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.initContext(WebClient.java:123)
    at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServletSupport.init(MessageServletSupport.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:731)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:483)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:313)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
 WARN | Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@35038141{Apache ActiveMQ REST API,/api,file:///opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/webapps/api/,UNAVAILABLE}
javax.servlet.ServletException: MessageServlet==org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet@6da0705e{jsp=null,order=1,inst=true,async=true,src=DESCRIPTOR:file:///opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/webapps/api/WEB-INF/web.xml,STARTED}
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:731)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:483)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:313)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing brokerURL (specified via org.apache.activemq.brokerURL init-Param) or embedded broker
    at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.initConnectionFactory(WebClient.java:279)
    at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.initContext(WebClient.java:123)
    at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServletSupport.init(MessageServletSupport.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:632)
    ... 72 more
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/data/kahadb]
```

I have been able to enable hawtio via the jetty.xml file,
I am suspecting that the answer to this problem may in fact lay in configuring the adapter via beans in the jetty.xml file.
But I haven't been able to find anything on the web, in confirm this.

Has enyone been able to enable Keycloak authentication to jetty in activemq and can point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Is the jar containing `org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator` on the broker's classpath?

Comment: yes, it is a sub directory of the other jars for activemq and is called in the cmd sript via

-Dactivemq.classpath=/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3//conf:/opt/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.3/lib/:

Comment: Do you see the keycloak jetty adapter jars listed in the output of `-D--list-config`?